# Unable to create Instance of XSSFWorkbook using poi-3.9

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-poi

Need to change the old `HSSFWorkbook` based code `XSSFWorkbook`

Towards the task, i have added poi-3.9, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9, poi-ooxml-3.9 jars to my build path and changed the code as suggested in

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html

at `XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()` the flow control comes out of the flow at this line.

I try debugging the file, and observed that it was not able to create an instance for `XSSFWorkbook`.

But after reading from below url, 
http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/

i have added xmlbeans-2.3.0 jar, should i also add dom4j.jar also for this?

but still the same issue, control comes out from the line creation of instance for `XSSFWorkbook`. can any one please help me on this?

Comment: Can you post your attempt as well?

Comment: what is the exception you are getting_

Comment: Did you try making sure you'd included [all the dependencies listed on the Apache POI Website](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)? Things won't work if you're missing any of them

Comment: for my project i have placed jars poi-3.9, poi-ooxml-3.9, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9,xml-beans. should i also include dom4j jar as well?

Comment: it seems to be that poi-ooxml is dependent on dom4j jar also. Will try to add that also in build path. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved, after adding the dependent jar dom4j. Consolidating the details of jars needed for Apache POI 3.9 for XLSX format files to export are as follows,

Poi-,
poi-ooxml,
poi-ooxml-schems,
dom4j